# Java file uri with xml file null pointer exception

Tags: java, filenames, xml-parsing, filepath

I am using windows OS,
and want to parse xml file, but get null pointer error....

```
    public void print( )
    throws SAXException, IOException {

             DocumentBuilder builder;

            Document document = builder.parse( "D:\\my\\xml.xml");//null pointer exception

}
```

here is the solution:

```
public class DOMPrinter {

         private DocumentBuilder builder;


        public void print(String fileName )//, PrintStream out)
                throws SAXException, IOException {

            try
            {
                DocumentBuilderFactory fact= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                builder= fact.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = builder.parse( fileName);

            Node node = document.getDocumentElement();
              String root = node.getNodeName();
              System.out.println("Root Node: " + root);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
}
```

I didn't use DocumentBuilderFactory  to create DocumentBuilder , so that was a error.

Comment: you never instantiated `builder`...it's painfully obvious.

Comment: You may want to read the SO FAQ. You have asked 6 questions and accepted no answers. This will discourage people from answering your questions in the future.

Comment: Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you guys, I will do my best to repair that in near future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never instantiated `builder`. You need to say `builder = ...`;

Also, you can't have private fields inside a method. Delete the private keyword.

Comment: It was in class but I move it to function in order to simplify code, so I forget to change that.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Glad you fixed it :D